# Vuex not working in child component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-loader

The following simple code has been giving me a lot of headaches, since both some-component and the root instance log an error to the console instead of binding from the vuex object. What can i possibly be missing here?

```js
var state = {
 counter: 0
};
var mutations = {};
var store = new Vuex.Store({state, mutations});

var someComponent = Vue.extend({
  template: '<div>{{counter}}</div>',
  //data: function(){return {counter: 0}},
  vuex: {
    getters: {
      counter: getCounter
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
   'some-component': someComponent
  },
  store: store,
  vuex: {
   getters: {
    counter: getCounter
   }
  }
});


function getCounter(state) {
  return state.counter;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>vue-bug</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
     <span>{{counter}}</span>
     <some-component></some-component>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.0-rc.1/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/2.0.0-rc.1/vuex.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my code, i'm calling Vue.use(Vuex), but in this fiddle i don't have to (it says that Vuex is already registered). Also, please notice that if you uncomment the line with the data, the component renders properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using `Vue 2.0` you should be using `Vuex 2.0`. I am not 100% sure that Vue.js 2.0 is compatible with the version of Vuex you are using. Can you upgrade to Vuex 2.0?

Can you add `created` hook into your component and do `console.log(this.$store)` to see if your store is even injected into your component?

Provide jsFiddle, it's easier to debug then looking at above code.

Comment: @PrimozRome I heavily edited my original question to make it easier to reproduce, and updated the vuex version. Also, `console.log(this.$store)` tells me that the store is being injected. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Vue/Vuex 2.0 you should take a look to this [link](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/releases/tag/v2.0.0-rc.1). In vuex 2.0 you don't create a property `vuex` inside your components to set your getters and actions. Instead in your `store.js` file you define a getters object where you'll get the props from the state and then inject it to the store, like this:

```
const state = {
    counter: 0
}
const getters = {
    getCounter: state.counter
}

const actions = {}
const mutations = {}

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,   
 })
```

In your components you can just define the getters using computed properties, like this:

```
import { mapGetter, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
    template: '#some-template',
    computed: {
        yourFirstComputed() {},
        anotherOfYourComputed() {},
        ...mapGetters({
            getCounter: 'getCounter'
        })
    },
    methods: {
        yourMethod(){},
        ...mapActions({
             anyOfYourActions: 'anyOfYourActions'
        })
    }
}
```

Then you can call these props like you would with normal computed. 
I repeat, this apply for vuex 2 which i think you are using after reading the comments to the question.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, this seems to fix it! Per the release notes, the vuex component option has been deprecated. All i had to do then was add `computed: Vuex.mapGetters(['counter'])` after passing the getters and actions to the store constructor and the component now works properly.

Comment: Glad I could help ;)

Comment: Just a quick update for anyone that might find this same problem: even though the answer is right, i needed to do one more step to get my components obtained via require working. As discussed in [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/264), you need to replace your `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue'` with `import Vue from 'vue'`. Also, you need to add an `alias` to your webpack config resolve object: `alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    }`.